# Using Formatter::debug_list to implement Debug for a two-dimensional array

Tags: debugging, multidimensional-array, rust, traits

I'm wondering if it's possible to get this to compile.

```
impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for Array2<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let ref mut builder = f.debug_list();
        self.rows().fold(builder, |b, e| b.entry(e)).finish()
    }
}
```

`self.rows` is an iterator that yields `&[T]`.

The error here is that Sized is not implement for `[T]` in the context of `b.entry(e)`, which is bizarre because the iterator yields `&[T]` as mentioned before.

I'm not able to figure this out, in part because I can't make sense of the function signatures involved here.

```
fn entry(self, entry: &Debug) -> DebugList<'a, 'b>
```

Note the `&Debug`.

Yet the relevant documentation example is passing references `&i32` to the builder.

```
struct Foo(Vec<i32>);

impl fmt::Debug for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        self.0.iter().fold(fmt.debug_list(), |b, e| b.entry(e)).finish()
    }
}
```

With this much confusion there has to be something interesting to learn.

The desired output would be something like `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

A similar example that anyone can compile:

```
use std::fmt;

fn fmt<T: fmt::Debug>(vec: &Vec<T>, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    let ref mut builder = f.debug_list();
    vec.chunks(4).fold(builder, |b, e| b.entry(e)).finish()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`entry()` is defined thus:

```
pub fn entry(&mut self, entry: &fmt::Debug) -> &mut DebugList<'a, 'b>;
```

It takes a `fmt::Debug` *trait object*. Thus when you pass it a `&[T]`, it wants to cast it implicitly to `&fmt::Debug`. This, however, cannot be done, for trait objects can only be constructed of sized objects. The solution is to make a trait object of the sized slice; that is, pass something of type `&&[T]` which can then be implicitly converted to `&fmt::Debug`, containing the type `&[T]`. That is, `b.entry(&e)` instead of `b.entry(e)`.

Your `builder` line is unnecessary too and actually introduces lifetime problems; you should declare it as part of the `fold` call for convenience.

This leaves you with this as your final result:

```
impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for Array2<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        self.rows().fold(&mut f.debug_list(), |b, e| b.entry(&e)).finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Look like my Rust is a bit rusty. I was under the impression that a &Trait can only be constructed with an explicit cast.